# Discovery of spin-3 particle at LHCb

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, standard-model

I just read a [discussion on the CERN website](http://home.web.cern.ch/scientists/updates/2014/07/first-observation-heavy-flavored-spin-3-particle) regarding first observation of a heavy flavored spin-3 particle at LHCb. This appears to be a post from last July.

Is there anyone knowledgeable enough in this area who would be able to comment on some of the possible theoretical/ hypothetical implications of the existence of spin-3 particles? Is there any thought that their existence could imply additional fundamental forces?

Comment: There is nothing particular about a composite spin 3 particle. There would only be fundamental implications if it were a fundamental particle, which this isn't claimed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyone knowledgable enough in this area who would be able to comment on some of the possible theoretical/ hypothetical implications of the existence of spin 3 particles? Is there any thought that their existence could imply additional fundamental forces?

If you look at the presentation linked in the link you gave , [in page five](https://indico.cern.ch/event/308116/session/6/contribution/20/material/slides/0.pdf), you will see that spin 3 resonances have appeared in the charmed section. This is the first indication of similar spectroscopy in the beauty sector. The spin is a combination of quark spins and the angular momentum of the quarks within the resonance.

It is all about how the quarks bind into resonances which is mainly QCD though QED cannot be ignored in the modeling . The study of this spectroscopy will be useful in evaluating QCD phenomenological models. The fundamental forces still are strong, weak, electromagnetic and gravitional.

Answer (score 0):

As ACuriousMind said, the fact that the particle is composite makes it less earth-shattering. The interesting thing here (I think...not a high-energy guy) is that it's the first example of this kind of spin-3 particle, in particular flavored. Other composite spin-3 particles have been known before, the [first one I found](http://www.easyspin.org/documentation/isotopetable.html) was a Boron nucleus.

Comment: It was not the first time. It is the first time in B resonances. please see my answer for the link